# Filtering nested object from multiple parameres

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wish to be able to search for all values in an array with nested objects. The search param should not be a string, but an array of strings like this: ['1970','comedy','family']

how would I solve this with lodash? I've been trying for some time without being able to solve this.

Test data:

```
var movies = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        title: '22 Jump Street',
        category: 'Comedy',
        description: 'After making their way through high school (twice), big changes are in store for officers Schmidt and Jenko when they go deep undercover at a local college',
        director: {
            name: 'Phil',
            lastName: 'Lord',
            dob: '12-07-1975'
        },

    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        title: 'How to Train Your Dragon 2',
        category: 'Animation',
        description: 'When Hiccup and Toothless discover an ice cave that is home to hundreds of new wild dragons and the mysterious Dragon Rider, the two friends find themselves at the center of a battle to protect the peace.',
        director: {
            name: 'Dean',
            lastName: 'DeBlois',
            dob: '07-06-1970'
        },

    },
    {
        id: 3, 
        title: 'Maleficent',
        category: 'Family',
        description: 'A vengeful fairy is driven to curse an infant princess, only to discover that the child may be the one person who can restore peace to their troubled land.',
        director: {
            name: 'Robert',
            lastName: 'Stromberg',
            dob: '22-08-1970'
        },

    }
];
```

Comment: are you trying to 'pull' all movies that match the geners in the array by category ?

Comment: Im trying to collect the objects which have a match of all params given. Like if i give the search params ['family','Comedy'] none is found but if I give ['1970','is'] the objects with title of 'Maleficent' and 'How to Train Your Dragon 2' show be returned/shown.

Comment: if you are willing to skip search terms "id", "title" and the other keys, you could just `JSON.stringify()` each object and then test `indexOf` for each search term.. if that doesn't scale well for you - O(n*m) - you might need to create a [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) index for each object instead

Comment: Thats actually a great idea deathApril :) I would need some tweaking, but I like the approach. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended answer for @Aprillion comments:

```
function filterMovies(query) {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(query);
    var result = movies;

    params.forEach(function(param) {
        result = result.filter(function(movie) {
           return JSON.stringify(movie).indexOf(param) >= 0;
        });
    });

    return result;
}

console.log('filtered: ', filterMovies(['1970', 'Robert']));
```